# Who is this woman in The Magicians, and what was she referring to?

Tags: the-magicians, lev-grossman

In *The Magicians* by Lev Grossmman,

> a mantis woman in a black coach asks the protagonists if they serve the Bull.
>  She then fires a green arrow at Quentin, and then rides off.

My question is, what bull is she referring to? And who is she?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quote from the story that you are referring to is this:

> A muffled voice spoke from inside the carriage. “Do they bear the Horns?” This was evidently directed not at them but at the coachman, who had the better vantage point. If the coachman replied, he/she did so inaudibly. “Do you bear the horns?” This voice was louder and clearer. The advance party exchanged looks. “What do you mean, Horns?” Janet called. “We’re not from around here.” This was ridiculous. It was like talking to the Once-ler in Dr. Seuss. “Do you serve the Bull?” Now the voice sounded shriller to his ears, with high, twittering overtones. “Who’s the bull?” Quentin said, loudly and slowly, as if he were talking to somebody who didn’t speak English or was mildly retarded. There was no bull in the Plover books, so—? “We are visitors to your land. We do not serve the bull, or anybody else for that matter.”

The bull most likely actually means the rams, Ember and Umber, and when I read through it, that is what I took it to mean.  I always treated it as a creature trying to speak a language not native to her, and mixing up Ram and Bull.

It is also possible that she is referring to an unknown character, as

> during this time in Fillory there are a bunch of "False Kings" that have taken the throne and then died.

Having read all 3 books:

> a bull isn't presented like this ever again.